# Adding a custom auth logic for graphql queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a RESTful API with .NET Core. It has a custom auth logic.

I want to create a temporary solution and expose `/graphql` endpoint for the same service that should have a custom, different, authentication logic with custom policies.

Is it possible to separate auth schemas for [graphql](https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/security/authentication) and rest?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Middleware to process token.
Below is the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).